# Load JavaScript file according to controller in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have two controllers:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

In my assets folder, I have two JavaScript files:

```
home.coffee
welcome.coffee
```

I want to load my script according to the controller:

- `home.coffee` at `home/index` path only
- `welcome.coffee` at `welcome/index` path only

Comment: might want to take a look at require.js

Comment: i didn't understand you want you want to say exactly.

Comment: Trademark capitalization; grammar; noise reduction.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the asset pipeline will concat all the Javascript you specify in the `application.js` manifest. For conditional execution, one technique might be to search for a unique ID in the DOM. For example, your `home/index` view might have a `<div id="home" />` element, so in `home.coffee`, you write:

`$ ->
  return unless $('#home').length
  (...the rest of your code here)`